# Admin notifications from WooCommerce not working, customer notifications are

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store here: http://vanuatucoffeeroasters.com

Sometime between Jan. 17 and Jan. 26, the admin email notifications stopped working. However, when I place an order, I get a user email notification just fine.

What I have tried:

- Testing wp_mail using Email Log plugin (sends successfully)
- Testing PHP Mail using PHP mail test script (sends successfully)
- Sending email to the email address that's not receiving notifications (successful)
- Whitelisting the IP address of the sending server (no effect)
- Deactivating and reactivating WooCommerce (no apparent effect)

Here is my system report:

#### WordPress Environment

Home URL: http://vanuatucoffeeroasters.com
Site URL: http://vanuatucoffeeroasters.com
WC Version: 2.4.10
Log Directory Writable: ✔ /nfs/c07/h01/mnt/99231/domains/vanuatucoffeeroasters.com/html/wp-content/uploads/wc-logs/
WP Version: 4.3.8
WP Multisite: –
WP Memory Limit: 40 MB - We recommend setting memory to at least 64MB. See: Increasing memory allocated to PHP
WP Debug Mode: –
Language: en_US

#### Server Environment

Server Info: Apache/2.2.22
PHP Version: 5.6.21
PHP Post Max Size: 64 MB
PHP Time Limit: 300
PHP Max Input Vars: 7000
SUHOSIN Installed: –
MySQL Version: 5.1.72
Max Upload Size: 64 MB
Default Timezone is UTC: ✔
fsockopen/cURL: ✔
SoapClient: ✔
DOMDocument: ✔
GZip: ✔
Remote Post: ✔
Remote Get: ✔

#### Database

WC Database Version: 2.4.10
: 
woocommerce_api_keys: ✔
woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies: ✔
woocommerce_termmeta: ✔
woocommerce_downloadable_product_permissions: ✔
woocommerce_order_items: ✔
woocommerce_order_itemmeta: ✔
woocommerce_tax_rates: ✔
woocommerce_tax_rate_locations: ✔

#### Active Plugins (12)

Column Shortcodes: by Codepress – 0.6.6
Contact Form 7: by Takayuki Miyoshi – 4.3.1
Custom Sidebars: by WPMU DEV – 2.1.0.2
Email Log: by Sudar – 1.9.1
Bundle Rate Shipping Module for WooCommerce: by Eric Daams – 1.3.3
Regenerate Thumbnails: by Alex Mills (Viper007Bond) – 2.2.6
Smart WYSIWYG Blocks Of Content: by Coen Jacobs – 0.6.1
Responsive WordPress Slider - Soliloquy Lite: by Thomas Griffin – 2.4.0.8
Sucuri Security - Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening: by Sucuri
Inc – 1.8.3

WooCommerce Product Archive Customiser: by jameskoster – 0.5.0
WooCommerce: by WooThemes – 2.4.10
Yoast SEO: by Team Yoast – 3.0.7

#### Settings

Force SSL: –
Currency: USD ($)
Currency Position: left_space
Thousand Separator: ,
Decimal Separator: .
Number of Decimals: 2

#### API

API Enabled: ✔
API Version: 3.0.0

#### WC Pages

Shop Base: #715 - /buy-a-bag/
Cart: #659 - /cart/
Checkout: #451 - /checkout/
My Account: #452 - /my-account/

#### Taxonomies

Product Types: external (external)
grouped (grouped)
simple (simple)
variable (variable)

#### Theme

Name: LaMonte
Version: 1.2
Author URL: http://www.templatesquare.com/
Child Theme: ✔
Parent Theme Name: Klasik
Parent Theme Version: 0.7.13
Parent Theme Author URL: http://www.klasikthemes.com/
WooCommerce Support: ✔

#### Templates

Overrides: klasik/woocommerce/archive-product.php

Comment: Did you check the server email logs to see if it's being allowed to be sent? Also, it would be a good idea to check the MX records on your machine to make sure it's not trying to send to itself (the server) if your email address matches that of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of an odd issue with contact form 7 at the moment if you are using recaptcha plugins, if you use these turn them off for testing and then try a different plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, but somehow this problem has fixed itself. And the client is shutting down the site, so it is no longer an issue.